# using OR between different columns along with AND

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query as

```
$query = "SELECT id,link, shape, size, color, clarity, cut, price, markup, cert, certificateNumber, stockNumber FROM diamonds WHERE cert IN ('GIA,AGS') AND storeKey = '$storeKey' AND size BETWEEN $minCarat AND $maxCarat AND price BETWEEN $minPrice AND $maxPrice AND cut IN($cut) AND clarity IN ($clarity) AND color IN ($color) AND shape IN ($shape) ORDER BY price ASC";
```

It can be seen that it allows only those list of diamonds that have `cert Either GIA Or AGS`

I want to add another condition. The table has a column "link" It can be either empty or Non empty. If i use either GIA Or AGS many of the diamonds will be excluded which has link not empty. I want to add condition for link too. Something like

```
cert IN ('GIA,AGS') Or link != ''
```

How can i add Or in addition to AND with other values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT 
           id,link,shape,size,
           color, clarity, cut, price,
           markup, cert, certificateNumber,stockNumber
         FROM 
            diamonds 
        WHERE 
              (cert IN ('GIA,AGS') or link != '')
          AND storeKey = '$storeKey'
          AND size BETWEEN $minCarat AND $maxCarat
          AND price BETWEEN $minPrice AND $maxPrice 
          AND cut IN($cut)
          AND clarity IN ($clarity)
          AND color IN ($color)
          AND shape IN ($shape)
       ORDER BY price";
```

Do not see any problems to just add `OR` statement

Comment: so just the brackets?

Comment: yes, exactly. You should operate bracket to set priority